# Setting myButton.Enabled = true causes radiobutton's CheckedChanged handler to fire

Tags: c#, winforms, events, radio-button, focus

I have absolutely no programmatic links or properties set such that my CheckedChanged fires as a result of anything except checking the radio button.

However, when I click a different, unrelated button, the button's click handler fires (this is expected). In this  click handler, the button disables itself (it re-enables on a different button's click), which then triggers myRadioButton_CheckedChanged handle for an unrelated radiobutton fires.

The call stack that I'm seeing is essentially

myRadioButton_CheckedChanged (...)
myButton_Click(...)
Main(...)

The line in myButton_Click that is triggering the myRadioButton_CheckedChanged is apparently

myButton.Enabled = false;

The related code is:

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // L-R
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            orientation_left = 3;
            pictureBox2.Invalidate();
            Debug.Print("left {0}", orientation_left);
        }
    }

private void select1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("select1click");

        if (select1Down == false)
        {
            // ... stuff
            select1.Enabled = false;        // Causing the CheckedChanged to fire
            select2.Enabled = false;
            select1Down = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I can confirm this strange behavior. Let me dig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it.

Check the TabOrder on your Button and RadioButton.

Seems that when you disable the Button, the focus is shifted to the next control, which is probably your RadioButton, causing it to become checked.

On my test From, all I had to do was to make sure that the RadioButton's TabOrder was not right after the Button.

Cheers

EDIT:

This seems to be a known problem as I just found this MSDN thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/77fbec3b-1f63-42e1-a200-19b261b63794/the-radiobutton-clicked-event-is-fired-without-the-radio-button-beeing-clicked-?forum=winforms

Comment: This sounds plausible, oh my goodness. Will report back momentarily, you brilliant responder, you. <3 (although this workaround is pretty hacky -_- )

Comment: I hear you. First time I ever see that situation.

Comment: You got it; thanks so much. That's definitely a bug.

Comment: First time I'm seeing this too, I'm bluffed. :p

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it's kinda hacky but it works without changing anything to the tab order:

```
private void select1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!select1Down)
    {
        // ... stuff

        SendKeys.SendWait("{Tab}");

        select1.Enabled = false;
        select2.Enabled = false;
        select1Down = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: does that even compile ?

Comment: My question was rhetorical. Your code doesn't compile. Please make sure you post relevant code.

Comment: I didn't get to trying this, but the above answer seemed a little bit more graceful. Thanks @Crono.

Comment: @MarkS As I said my original answer was a guess. The part I was missing is declaring a new `Action` object. I tested the corrected code but it didn't work anyway. However I *did* find another way around this, **without messing with the tab order**. See my edited answer. :)

Comment: @mrlucmorin Would you please reconsider your vote given the edited answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Crono I'll give you an upvote for effort. Shh, don't tell anyone. ;)

Comment: @Crono Ok, your code now compiles. Hope you understand the point that if we're going to answer programming questions, the least we can do is make sure that our code compiles (or else make it clear that it is pseudo-code). Removed my downvote.

Comment: @mrlucmorin Well I *did* mention it was a guess, but indeed that might have been ambiguous, sorry. However I believe that downvotes should be for totally unuseful answers, not for missing semicolons or the likes. Comments exists for that. In any case, no hard feelings. :)

Comment: @Crono Actually the downvote was not for your answer, but for your comment about "writing down random characters on that internet thing" in reply to my comment. I perceived it as a "I don't care my answer is wrong" attitude. As for "hard feelings", I never had any ;-)

Comment: @mrlucmorin that was actually sarcasm (okay, arrogance too :) ) because I was dead certain the code *would* compile (darn that missing `new Action` statement!). Your question given the context of my code being very short and straightforward led me to believe you'd never seen a lambda expression before (some people haven't seen the light yet), so I felt like answering something funny. Reading it again I now see it's kinda cold, yes. I should've thrown in a smiley or something. :p Anyway, I really am sorry about that. I never meant to be rude. :)